# How to add gesture recognizer to custom UIView (XIB) programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

### Intro

I trying to adding a tap recognizer to an instance of my custom `UIView` class `CardView`. So I created a custom view `xib` and link my Swift class file `CardView.swift` via `File's Owner`. After that I connected each outlet to the corresponding UI elements.

I would like to add my custom View `CardView` programmatically to my ViewController and attach a tapGesture to the newly created view.

### CardView class:

```
class CardView: UIView {

    // Delcare outlets
    @IBOutlet var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!


    //MARK: Initialization
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CardView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addSubview(view)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }

}
```

### ViewController class

In the `viewDidLoad()` function of ViewController.swift I created an instance of CardView():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let cardView = CardView()
        self.view.addSubview(cardView)

        // Style cardView instance
        cardView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        cardView.view.center.x = self.view.center.x
        cardView.view.center.y = self.view.center.y

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(gestureRecognizer:)))
        cardView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    }
```

Than I add tapGesture to my `cardView` just like normal using Swift:

```
let tapGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(gestureRecognizer:)))    cardView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

And add the corresponding function to be called:

```
func handleTap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

### Main question/problem

The problem that I have with adding a tap Gesture Recognizer to the newly created CardView - an instance of the CardView - is that the function `handleTap()` is never been called.

I already tried several things like add `cardView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` to both files (`ViewController.swift` and `CardView.swift` class). Also add in one of these files and not in the other one.

After declaring the type of gesture, I also try to add it my the super view, the one that is linked with the `ViewController.swift file`. When I tap on the screen, the function will be triggered, but not with my own created custom UIView.

Beside those I also tried to add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to my VC class with no result.

`class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {}`

In my `viewDidLoad()` function before I connect the gesture to my `cardView` I added this extra line: `tapGesture.delegate = self`.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(gestureRecognizer:)))
tapGesture.delegate = self
architectView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

Comment: Try bringing the card view to front.

Comment: I have simplified my code. Still get no message after dragging. Please check my updated question above.

Comment: You are adding gesture to the first card above which there are many other cards i guess. Then how will your first card detect gesture. So move it to front or add gesture to each card inside loop and detect each card using gesture.view.

Comment: @DeepakKumar I changed my code, so there is only one card. Still get the panGesture not working..

Comment: Did you finally make it?

Comment: did you resolve it ???

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with Custom UIView.

I made **Xib** and **swift** file and connected it.
Then add gesture to UIView, however, it doesn't work.
I changed UIView to UIButton to solve the problem but doesn't work.

To solve my problem is

### AutoLayout Problem

When I run the app and debug by **Debug view hierarchy** , there is ambiguous
problem with my customUIView.

By print description of UIView, I can notify it has frame(0,0), subView has own frame on the other hand.

So I delete and make from the scratch, run test each time and solve it.
Also gesture function works when clicked custom UIView.

I hope this works to you. I saw your code and it doesn't seem have problem from your code, so check xib file and auto layout those label and image.

Answer (score -1):

Correct `UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dragged))`
 with

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dragged(sender:)))
```